# How to point composer to the right PHP version?

Tags: php, versioning, composer

I have several versions of PHP installed on my server, and I use FastCGI to select the one to use for a certain setup.

I am trying to install PIMCore and it has a Composer project for that. I have setup the projectdir to use PHP7.3 and that works fine. However, when I try to run the PIMCore Composer installer, it complains about PHP5.6:

```
$ COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer create-project pimcore/demo my-project


 [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                         
  Could not find package pimcore/demo with stability stable in a version installable using your PHP version 5.6.40.  


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]
```

I tried aliasing PHP7.3 to `php`, to no avail.

How can I let Composer know to use `php73` instead of `php`?

Answer (score 0):

This was actually too easy:

```
$ COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 php73 /usr/bin/composer create-project pimcore/demo my-project
```